Derivative of $y= \frac{x}{1+x^2} - \arctan x$
Let $y= \frac{x}{1+x^2} - \arctan x$
Differentiating using quotient rule on the first term, $$\begin{align}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}&=\frac{(1+x^2)(1)-x(2x)}{(1+x^2)^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2}\\&=\frac{1+x^2 -2x^2 - 1 + x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\end{align}$$
Which gives $0$. Can someone point out where I went wrong?

Apologies if the mathjax is wierd, feel free to correct it.

The last $x^2$ should have a $-1$ in front by distributivity.

Silliest mistake ever.  Sorry.

It would perhaps be easier to write $y = x \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \arctan x$ and use the product rule, rather than the quotient rule. Then it's obvious that there is cancellation and that you will be left with $y' = x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

$\frac{1+x^2 -2x^2 - 1 \color{red}{+} x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}
$
I suspect something fishy here.

Oh wow. That is one of the dumbest mistakes ever. Sorry.

@Haider no problem... mistakes do happen, my friend :)

Because $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$, you should subtract 1 and subtract $x^2$ continuously, not subtract 1 and add $x^2$.
